# How am I supposed to use a Postgresql docker image/container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker. I'm still trying to wrap my head around all this.

I'm building a node application (REST api), using Postgresql to store my data.

I've spent a few days learning about docker, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing things the way I'm supposed to.

So here are my questions:

1. I'm using the official docker postgres 9.5 image as base to build my own (my Dockerfile only adds plpython on top of it, and installs a custom python module for use within plpython stored procedures). I created my container as suggedsted by the postgres image docs:

   docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres

   After I stop the container I cannot run it again using the above command, because the container already exists. So I start it using docker start instead of docker run. Is this the normal way to do things? I will generally use docker run the first time and docker start every other time?
2. Persistance: I created a database and populated it on the running container. I did this using pgadmin3 to connect. I can stop and start the container and the data is persisted, although I'm not sure why or how is this happening. I can see in the Dockerfile of the official postgres image that a volume is created (VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data), but I'm not sure that's the reason persistance is working. Could you please briefly explain (or point to an explanation) about how this all works?
3. Architecture: from what I read, it seems that the most appropriate architecture for this kind of app would be to run 3 separate containers. One for the database, one for persisting the database data, and one for the node app. Is this a good way to do it? How does using a data container improve things? AFAIK my current setup is working ok without one.
4. Is there anything else I should pay atention to?

Thanks

EDIT: adding to my confusion, I just ran a new container from the debian official image (no Dockerfile, just docker run -i -t -d --name debtest debian /bin/bash). With the container running in the background, I attached to it using docker attach debtest and the proceeded to apt-get install postgresql. Once installed I ran (still from within the container) psql and created a table in the default postgres database, and populated it with 1 record. Then I exited the shell and the container stopped automatically since the shell wasn't running anymore. I started the container againg using docker start debtest, then attached to it and finally run psql again. I found everything is persisted since the first run. Postgresql is installed, my table is there, and offcourse the record I inserted is there too. I'm really confused as to why do I need a VOLUME to persist data, since this quick test didn't use one and everything apears to work just fine. Am I missing something here?

Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

> docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
>   -d postgres
>
> After I stop the container I cannot run it again using the above
>   command, because the container already exists.

Correct. You named it (`--name some-postgres`) hence before starting a new one, the old one has to be deleted, e.g. `docker rm -f some-postgres`

> So I start it using
>   docker start instead of docker run. Is this the normal way to do
>   things? I will generally use docker run the first time and docker
>   start every other time?

No, it is by no means normal for docker. Docker process containers are supposed normally to be [ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#containers-should-be-ephemeral:238d508e032e5771326119b3d1c5c7a0), that is easily thrown away and started anew.

2. > Persistance: ... I can stop and start
   >   the container and the data is persisted, although I'm not sure why or
   >   how is this happening. ...

That's because you are reusing the same container. Remove the container and the data is gone.

3. > Architecture: from what I read, it seems that the most appropriate
   >   architecture for this kind of app would be to run 3 separate
   >   containers. One for the database, one for persisting the database
   >   data, and one for the node app. Is this a good way to do it? How does
   >   using a data container improve things? AFAIK my current setup is
   >   working ok without one.

Yes, this is the good way to go by having separate containers for separate concerns. This comes in handy in many cases, say when for example you need to upgrade the postgres base image without losing your data (that's in particular where the data container starts to play its role).

4. > Is there anything else I should pay atention to?

When acquainted with the docker basics, you may take a look at [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) or similar tools that will help you to run multicontainer applications easier.

Comment: @RobertGrant depends on your situation. In some cases it might be good enough, sometimes you might want to have host volumes instead. Some setups prohibit volumes at all.

Comment: that seems to be an edge case, and not something that should be written without a big warning sign in an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Short and simple:

1. What you get from the official postgres image is a ready-to-go postgres installation along with some gimmicks which can be configured through environment variables. With `docker run` you create a container.  The container lifecycle commands are `docker start/stop/restart/rm` Yes, this is the Docker way of things.
2. Everything inside a volume is persisted. Every container can have an arbitrary number of volumes. Volumes are directories either defined inside the Dockerfile, the parent Dockerfile or via the command `docker run ... -v /yourdirectoryA -v /yourdirectoryB ...`. Everything outside volumes is lost with `docker rm`. Everything including volumes is lost with `docker rm -v`
3. It's easier to show than to explain. See this readme with Docker commands on Github, read how I use the official PostgreSQL image for Jira and also add NGINX to the mix: [Jira with Docker PostgreSQL](https://github.com/blacklabelops/jira/tree/master/jirasoftware#database-setup). Also a data container is a cheap trick to being able to remove, rebuild and renew the container without having to move the persisted data.
4. Congratulations, you have managed to grasp the basics! Keep it on! Try docker-compose to better manage those nasty `docker run ...`-commands and being able to manage multi-containers and data-containers.

Note: You need a blocking thread in order to keep a container running! Either this command must be explicitly set inside the Dockerfile, see CMD, or given at the end of the `docker run -d ... /usr/bin/myexamplecommand` command. If your command is NON blocking, e.g. `/bin/bash`, then the container will always stop immediately after executing the command.